# Drush finding 3rd party module but can't install

Tags: drush

Have moneyscripts modules installed and drush does not update these 3rd party scripts but still I get a notification via drupal that update is required.

So I used drush up command but failed to update saying could not find download. Then I manually wget install the update but now if I drush up after manual install it won't stop trying to update the core.

How can I make drush IGNORE moneyscripts considering it can't install them anyway?

Or do I just have to select no everytime it asks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see --lock, described in drush help pm-update:

```
--lock

     Add a persistent lock to remove the  
     specified projects from              
     consideration during updates.  Locks 
     may be removed with the --unlock     
     parameter, or overridden by          
     specifically naming the project as a 
     parameter to pm-update or            
     pm-updatecode.  The lock does not    
     affect pm-download.  See also the    
     update-advanced project for similar  
     and improved functionality.
```